Can we construct the circular permutation from partial partition info?
Imagine a circular permutation of n points on a circle, if we draw a line connecting any pair of points, the rest of the points are divided into two sets that are on the same side. We can partition a circular permutation like this for every pair. Of course, if the two points are neighbours on the circle, there would be one set containing all points except that pair. So, we would know who the neighbours are by looking at partitions if we had the full partition info for all pairs. However, lets say that we have partial information about the partitions for all pairs.
For every pair, we have a few sets of points. The points in the same set are known to be on the same side if we draw a line connecting the given pair. In our info, there will be more than two sets with many missing points for a pair. This only means the points in the same set will be on the same side, and some of them will merge in the full known case, because there are two sides for a pair, one if they are neighbours. The question is:

Can we construct the circular permutation from partial partitions for all pairs?

Also, I could not find the name of this particular set of partitions for all pairs after looking at some combinatorics books and chatbots. I would also appreciate if you direct me to a source that has this problem setting and hopefully a solution.

How much partial information do we know? Do I understand correctly that your data is of the form "the points $a$ and $b$ lie on the same side / on different sides of the chord $cd$" for various quadruples of points $a,b,c,d$ on the circle? Are you interested in results of the form "if we have $x$ many such statements, then we can uniquely recover the relative cyclic order of the points" or "if we have this specific set of statements, then we can uniquely recover..."?

every pair has to have n-2 points in their union of sets, we have around 1/3 of that. The data is like this: (a, b):{c, d, e},{f, g} This means that for cord (ab), the points (c,d,e) are on the same side. The data has all pairs, but for inference I use pair info to look at quadruples if their relative order can be known(only 3 possible circular permutation for 4 points). Probably a prerequisite question, how much of the sets are enough to describe a unique permutation, but I'm interested in finding the permutation.

yes, a line cuts the circle at two points and separates the circle into two disjoint sets of points. Union of these sets must have n-2 points, excluding the pair. it is like the numbers on a watch, if you choose 9  and 12 as the pair, the other numbers will be in two sets, depending on which side of the chosen pair: {10,11} and {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. if the numbers are consecutive, all others will be on the same side for them.

@puzzler: "Between" was confusing since it sounded like you draw a line crossing the circle in between of two points. I've edited the question to avoid this confusion. As for the problem itself, it somewhat resembles the cyclopeptide sequencing problem in bioinformatics. See Chapters 4 and 11 in Bioinformatics Algorithms textbook (the latter chapter addresses the presence of noise and missing data, like in your problem).

The question is more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/
